# php mssql mysql integration error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Good day - I have a php script importing data from mssql to mysq. 
But get an error : expected a [

here is the code
error received.
" syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ']' in /var/www/integration/assetsim$"

```
  // Execute the MS-Sql stament and loop over the data   
  $qt=mssql_query($query); 
  while($nt=mssql_fetch_array($qt)) 
  { 

     // error occurs here!!!!!!!! with echo!!

    echo "$nt[SERNUM]"; 
    echo "<br>"; 


   } 

   $myquery = INSERT ignore INTO x3assetimport(PRODUCT_CATEGORY, STOCK_SITE, PRODUCT_CODE)     VALUES('".$nt[SERNUM]."', '".$nt[STOFCY]."','".$nt[TCLCOD]."'); 
    mysql_query($myquery) or Die("MySQL Query Failed " . mysql_error()); 

    echo "done";
```

Comment: FYI, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead.

Comment: **Never** use quotes when you want to print arrays. It does work in some cases, but you shouldn't do it ever. Just use `echo $nt['SERNUM'];`

Comment: You need to fix your code on certain points. **1.** Like @iswinky said, `mysql_` functions are deprecated, don't use them. **2.** Like @EduardLuca said, never use quotes when you want to print arrays. **3.** Use correct indentation, it helps you and others read your code more easily. **4.** You forgot a double quote right next to `$myquery = `. **5.** You are using strings as constants when you try to read a value of an associative array. Keys of an associative array are just strings. Write `$nt['SERNUM']` instead of `$nt[SERNUM]`. I suggest you read more about coding.

Answer (score 0):

the query should be like -

```
$myquery = 'INSERT ignore INTO x3assetimport(PRODUCT_CATEGORY, STOCK_SITE, PRODUCT_CODE)     VALUES("'.$nt[SERNUM].'", "'.$nt[STOFCY].'","'.$nt[TCLCOD].'")';
```

also escaping must be considered.the error is coming for syntactical mistakes.

Comment: The query should also have [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because composing queries this way is seriously dangerous.

Comment: yes that should be.. i am just pointing out the syntactical error.

Comment: Thanks all will try it, funny thing is this works in my test server bur not in production?

Comment: I am getting Notice: Undefined index: sernum. I am doing a select statement from mssql  $query="SELECT top 10
  I.TCLCOD_0 ,
A.STOFCY_0 ,
A.ITMREF_0 ,
I.ITMDES1_0 ,
A.LASRCPDAT_0,
A.QTYSTU_0,
A.CREDAT_0,
A.CREUSR_0,
A.UPDDAT_0,
A.UPDUSR_0
 FROM PILOT.STOCK A
 LEFT JOIN PILOT.ITMMASTER I
  ON A.ITMREF_0 = I.ITMREF_0
 "; 
  $mydbconn=mysql_connect($mydbserver,$mydbuser,$mydbpass); 
   mysql_select_db($mydbname, $mydbconn) or die("Unable to Open The MySql Database"); 
   
$qt=mssql_query($query); 

while($nt=mssql_fetch_array($qt)) 
    { 
      echo $nt['I.TCLCOD_0'];
      echo "<br>"; 
   }